# Invalid SYN cookies received，but no syncookie sent?

Tags: linux, tcp

`cat /proc/net/netstat` shows that：

```
SyncookiesSent:0
SyncookiesRecv:0
SyncookiesFailed:34954
```

Num of bad syncookies is received, but system don't send any syncookie。
What i expect is that bad received sysncookies is less than sent syncookies.
Who knows the reason?

2.6.32：

```
static struct sock *tcp_v4_hnd_req(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct tcphdr *th = tcp_hdr(skb);
    const struct iphdr *iph = ip_hdr(skb);
    struct sock *nsk;
    struct request_sock **prev;
    /* Find possible connection requests. */
    struct request_sock *req = inet_csk_search_req(sk, &prev, th->source,
                               iph->saddr, iph->daddr);
    if (req)
        return tcp_check_req(sk, skb, req, prev);

    nsk = inet_lookup_established(sock_net(sk), &tcp_hashinfo, iph->saddr,
            th->source, iph->daddr, th->dest, inet_iif(skb));

    if (nsk) {
        if (nsk->sk_state != TCP_TIME_WAIT) {
            bh_lock_sock(nsk);
            return nsk;
        }
        inet_twsk_put(inet_twsk(nsk));
        return NULL;
    }

#ifdef CONFIG_SYN_COOKIES
    if (!th->rst && !th->syn && th->ack)
        sk = cookie_v4_check(sk, skb, &(IPCB(skb)->opt)); <== check received ack.
#endif
    return sk;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant section from cookie_v4_check in `net/ipv4/syncookies.c`:

```
    if (tcp_synq_no_recent_overflow(sk) ||
    (mss = cookie_check(skb, cookie)) == 0) {
    NET_INC_STATS_BH(sock_net(sk), LINUX_MIB_SYNCOOKIESFAILED);
    goto out;
}

NET_INC_STATS_BH(sock_net(sk), LINUX_MIB_SYNCOOKIESRECV);
```

So, if:

1. There has been a recent overflow requiring SYN cookies, and
2. The cookie fails to checks out as a valid regular SYN packet or SYN cookie,

then `SyncookiesFailed` gets incremented.  Otherwise, `SyncookiesRecv` gets incremented.  So, if `CONFIG_SYN_COOKIES` is enabled in the kernel, and you've been under a new connection load that requires it, you'd expect `SyncookiesSent` to be positive, and `SyncookiesRecv` to be positive (but less).  As it is, it looks like the only ones you've gotten are invalid.

We're seeing similar numbers, and we think it is because [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)'s default rules include dropping packets with an invalid state, which may include outgoing and incoming SYN cookies.  You might want to check your firewall config and logs to see if unexpected dropped packets are occurring.

Or, you may just be getting invalid SYN cookies, due to some random attacker.  In that case, though, I'd expect some SYN cookies sent.

Answer (score 0):

The code that John Witlock posted is actually a bug and was fixed in v3.19: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/646697b9e3fef913bb6393ebfb6115c442a96be7 Before that counter was incremented without sending a syncookie.